# Виды (типы) памяти

Tags: storage

В книге Эккеля (Effective java) описано 5 видов памяти:

1. Registers (Регистры)
2. Stack (Стек)
3. Heap (Куча)
4. Constant storage (Постоянная память)
5. Non-Ram Storage (Не оперативная память)

С первыми тремя понятно - первая в процессоре, вторая и третья в RAM (оперативной памяти).

Собственно вопрос: что за 4 и 5? В чем их различия? Пишет, что Constant storage — это ROM память. Это винт, CD-диск? Примеры девайсов с этим видом памяти?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что под *Constant storage* подразумевается [ПЗУ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) (PROM), уже давно почти всюду это на самом деле EPROM, EEPROM или flash, т.е. энергонезависимая память, содержимое которой может быть изменено (перезаписано).

Часто такая память (или ее часть) не являются частью адресного пространства к которому ОС имеет непосредственный доступ. Обычно в ней хранятся микропрограммы и данные (параметры), которые необходимы на "аппаратном" уровне. Т.е. с точки зрения ОС (и прикладного софта) это неотъемлемая часть "железа".

Под *Non-Ram Storage* видимо подразумеваются все традиционные внешние носители (HDD, SSD, CD и т.д.).

Точнее, не зная контекста (книги), сказать не могу.

Comment: Вы правы, нашел инфу что A good example of ROM in the computer is the computer BIOS, a PROM chip that stores the programming needed to begin the initial computer start up process. Только вот в книге написано что значение констант могут размещаться в ROM памяти, если речь идет о встроенных системах...Вот и интересно куда это java засовывает константы ?? И что за встроенные системы для JAVы?